# Comparing two Passwords in Registration form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, passwords

I am trying to find a way that I can compare two hashed password from my registration form before the information gets added to the database.

However I am not sure if I am dong this correctly at all and if I have missed a load out that will allow me to do this.

Would I need to place completely separate variables that link to my passwords posted in the form? And would I need to execute my statements first before trying to compare the passwords?

Would appreciate some guidance. Thank you.

```
require 'connection.php';

$message = '';

if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Role, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :role, :email, :username, :password)";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

  $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $_POST['firstname']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $_POST['lastname']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':role', $_POST['role']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
  $password = $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
  $confirmpassword = $stmt->bindParam(':confirmpassword', password_hash($_POST['confirmpassword'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));

if($password == $confirmpassword):

  if ($stmt->execute()):
    $message = 'Well done! You have successfully registered with us!';
    header('Location:loginPage.php');
  else:
    $message = 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
  else:
    $message = 'Your passwords do not match, please enter them correctly.';
endif;

endif;

endif;
```

Comment: Set `$_POST['password']` to `$password`, and `$confirmpassword` to `$_POST['confirmpassword']`. I think if you `var_dump` `$password` currently that will be an object, not a string.

Comment: Oh, and why are you doing `$confirmpassword = $stmt->bindParam(':confirmpassword'...`? You don't need that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thought I would need a variable to compare to whilst executing the statements?

Comment: I've posted a community wiki answer below.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you for help, will definitely look into this.

Answer (score 2):

Submitting as a community wiki. Everyone (qualified) is welcome to modify.

As chris85 stated in comments:

> *"Set $_POST['password'] to $password, and $confirmpassword to $_POST['confirmpassword']. I think if you var_dump $password currently that will be an object, not a string."*

What you're (most likely) looking to do, is to check if the user's entered password in your *unshown* HTML form matches both inputs.

```
if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword']; // assuming the same in HTML form name attribute

if($password == $confirmpassword):

  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Role, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :role, :email, :username, :password)";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

...

  else:
    $message = 'Your passwords do not match, please enter them correctly.';
```

Check for errors.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

If you wish to verify a password from a SELECT later on, use `password_verify()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Plus, as I stated in comments, I don't see why you're using:

```
$confirmpassword = $stmt->bindParam(':confirmpassword', ...
```

That is overkill and there is no use for it really and it will also throw you an error about it, since there is no bind for it in your query.

- Just remove it.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, will look into this as well.